# Passing array of data to other page using session in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, session, csv

I have some problem passing array of data in Php using session:
In my class, I have this function:

```
 public function check_dupID($id)
 {
     $this->stmt="select id from student where id='$id'";
     $this->res = mysql_query($this->stmt);
     $this->num_rows = mysql_num_rows($this->res);
     if($this->num_rows == 1)
     {
         while($this->row = mysql_fetch_array($this->res))
         {
             $dup_id = $this->row[0];
             return $dup_id;
         }
    }
}
```

This code checks for duplicate ID of a student. Now, the reason for this is that I uploaded the file in the database using ".csv" file.

Before Uploading it I put all the data in the csv file into an array. Now, I check it one by one:
//created the variable for checking

```
$id = $check->check_dupID($array[0]);


if($id == TRUE)
{

    session_start();
    $_SESSION['id']; = $id;//passing it to the next back to array again. 
    $redirect->page($error);
}
```

Now when it redirect it gives me the result of an "Array" and if I parse it using foreach it shows only one id but there is more than of that. I want to know how to display it all.

Comment: `session_start();` needs to be the first thing that happens in the file. Not entirely sure this solves your issue, but you can start with that.

Comment: I tried it but still the same..

Comment: You are returning `$dup_itemcode`, but I do not see where that is set in your function.

Comment: sorry for this, it should be return $dup_id. .I'll the edit code .. thanks

Comment: although I edit it still don't work..

Answer (score 0):

This code will return the duplicate id when it is found for the first time. If you want to return all the duplicate ids, then add them into an array using the while loop and then return it.
To do this modify your code like this:

```
    public function check_dupID($id)
 {
     $this->stmt="select id from student where id='$id'";
     $this->res = mysql_query($this->stmt);
     $this->num_rows = mysql_num_rows($this->res);
     $dup_id = array();// added here to prevent invalid argument supplied to foreach loop error if nothing is found
     if($this->num_rows >1)
     {

         while($this->row = mysql_fetch_array($this->res))
         {
            $dup_id[] = $this->row[0];// adding duplicates into the array

         }
         return $dup_id;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. . i'll try this, I get back to you after. Thanks

Comment: still the same, I got only one result instead of four results but thanks for your help, I appreciate it.

Comment: how will it return more than one rows if this statement is here ** if($this->num_rows == 1) { **  .Edited my answer. Please check it now.

Comment: The better question is how will it return more than one if the query only allows for one ID to be input each time the function is called.

Comment: @BrianCohan He is trying to find the duplicate entries. Rows with the same id.\

Comment: @user3651152: Just **var_dump($this->num_rows);** and let us know the output.

Comment: That is how it looks to be implemented, but I think the intended design may be different

Comment: I got it already. Thanks for your help in passing it to the next page I used only $id which means always get the only one value, instead I pass to an array $get_id and pass the $get_id to the session and parse it and that solved my problem. . Thanks for you help guyz, I appreciate it. .

Answer (score 0):

This code fixes my problem:

```
if($id == TRUE)
        {
        $get_id = array();
        $get_id[] = $id;
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['id']; = $get_id;//passing it to the next back to array again. 
            $redirect->page($error);
        }
```

Comment: Passing to the session as $id means I pass it as a single value. So instead, I created a new array which name is $get_id which means get the all values in the $id variable which is an array in function. Next, I pass the $get_id to the SESSION and parse it and that solved my problem..